# What does this do? - ArgName in ("-h", "--help") [in python]

Tags: python

Would someone be able to explain what this means?  Please use simple terms that a random guy off the street would be able to understand. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking for an answer?

Comment: It tests whether the value of `ArgName` is contained in the tuple.

Comment: It raises a `SyntaxError` because the curly quotes are not quotes, and not a valid part of an identifier, literal, or anything else that can be an argument to the `-` operator.

Comment: @abarnert, the curly quotes are added by the site, they are not part of the original title (you can double-check in the [edit] page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try testing these things in your console... They are pretty self-explanatory.

```
# set a value for ArgName 
>>> ArgName = "-h"
# see if that value is in this tuple
>>> ArgName in ("-h","--help")
True # because ArgName = '-h' which is in the tuple
>>> ArgName = "--help"
>>> ArgName in ("-h","--help")
True # because ArgName = '--help' which is in the tuple
>>> ArgName = "something"
>>> ArgName in ("-h","--help")
False # because ArgName = 'something' which is NOT in the tuple
```